# Editing images on CKeditor brings up the Drupal image uploader not IMCE in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, files

I'm using IMCE to upload images on the CKeditor. The insertions of images works fine but when I double click an existing image to edit it, it only opens on the normal image uploader.

Any idea what I'm missing ?